# public interface differences between vs2008 and vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I just created a simple project in VS2010, C# dotnet 3.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Business.Util
{
        public interface ICalculateCurrent<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4>
        {
            bool GetValue(T1 obj1, T2 obj2, T3 obj3, T4 obj4);
        }

        public static class test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            }
        }
}
```

Fine, doesn't do anything at the moment but it compiles.

Then realizing that I really wanted to be doing this in VS2008, dotnet3.5 I created the exact same code and I get nothing but errors regarding the interface;

```
Invalid token 'in' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Type expected
Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

The project references are both the same.  What am I missing on this?

thanks.

Comment: Not to be too nitpicky, but whether or not a given code sample will compile is dependent on which version of the compiler you're using, not which version of the text editor you're using.  The fact that different editors are often released at around the same time as new versions of the compiler doesn't really make them equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variant interfaces require the VS2010 version of the C# compiler.  Even though you're targeting .NET 3.5, it was still using the new compiler.

No way to do this with VS2008, sorry.  .NET 3.5 includes runtime support for variant interfaces but the older C# compiler doesn't.

If you aren't using interface variance, just remove `in` all four times it appears on that line.

Comment: yes, the right answer - there's big confusion in between VS/IDE, C# and .NET and CLR versions (http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/versions.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The `in` keyword for generics was added to VS10. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx).

Comment: Actually, .NET has supported generic parameter variance for a long time.  It's the C# compiler that didn't until VS2010.

Comment: I had already edited my answer - we forget this as most of us are using vs10 w/ 4.0, not w/ 3.5. But thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

The `out` and `in` keywords and thus covariant and contravariant generic type parameters
are new to C# 4.0 (delivered with VS 2010).

Comment: The `in` and `out` keywords are part of C#, not the .NET Framework.  The .NET Framework (the CLR actually) supports variant generic interfaces since 2.x

Comment: That's correct. Therfore you can target a previous version of the framework, even is you use the `in` and `out` keywords.